# How do I change the order of integration for this parabolic wedge triple integral?

Tags: calculus, integration

The question at hand asked me to change the order of the triple integral $$\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{x^{2}}^{1}\int_{0}^{y} f(x,y,z)dz dy dx$$
to $dy dz dx$.

[image: solid drawing]

It seemed straight forward at first, seeing that y is bounded by $y=z$ and $y=1$, and my region in the x-z plane would look like this:

[image: this]

But this region seems to say that z is bound by $z=0$ and $z=1$, and x bound by $x=-1$ and $x=1$. But putting those as my bounds would just express a rectangular block cut in half and not the solid. I suppose my initial assumption of y being bound by $y=z$ and $y=1$ doesn't allow me to take into the account the $y=x^{2}$ also binding it. How should I approach this?

Comment: What does a cross-section of this surface look like if you set $x=c$ for some $c$ between $-1$ and $1$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The given integral is $\displaystyle \int_{-1}^{1}\int_{x^{2}}^{1}\int_{0}^{y} f(x,y,z) \ dz \ dy \ dx$

As it shows in your drawing, the region is bound by a parabolic cylinder $y=x^2$ and plane $y = 1$ between $z = 0$ and $z = y$.

For order of integral $dy$ then $dz$ and $dx$ last, we note that **for any given $x$**,

- $y$ is bound below by the parabolic cylinder, when $0 \leq z \leq x^2$.
- $y$ is bound below by the plane $y = z$, when $x^2 \leq z \leq 1$.

The upper bound of $y$ is $1$ in both cases. So the integral in changed order becomes,

$\displaystyle \int_{-1}^1 \int_{0}^{x^2} \int_{x^2}^1 f(x, y, z) \ dy \ dz \ dx + 
\int_{-1}^1 \int_{x^2}^{1} \int_{z}^1 f(x, y, z) \ dy \ dz \ dx $

Comment: This looks correct +1. Please note that the integrand has gone missing in the first integral in last line.

Comment: @Koro thank you for pointing out the typo. I just edited.

Answer (score 1):

Good known way is draw figure in $\Bbb{R}^3$, to view its bounds. This gives  intuition to follow then formal way: we have
$$A =\left\lbrace \begin{array}{l}
-1 \leqslant x \leqslant 1 \\
x^2 \leqslant y \leqslant 1 \\
0 \leqslant z \leqslant y
\end{array}
\right\rbrace  =\left\lbrace \begin{array}{l}
0 \leqslant z \leqslant 1 \\
z \leqslant y \leqslant 1 \\
-\sqrt{y} \leqslant x \leqslant \sqrt{y}
\end{array}
\right\rbrace = B = \left\lbrace \begin{array}{l}
0 \leqslant y \leqslant 1 \\
0 \leqslant z \leqslant y \\
-\sqrt{y} \leqslant x \leqslant \sqrt{y}
\end{array}
\right\rbrace $$
To prove $A=B$ formally we need to show definition of sets equality, but to obtain right side we need to solve inequalities.

**Addition.**
In integrals it is
$$\int\limits_{-1}^{1}\int\limits_{x^2}^{1}\int\limits_{0}^{y}f(x,y,z)dzdydx= \int\limits_{-1}^{1}dx\int\limits_{x^2}^{1}dy\int\limits_{0}^{y}f(x,y,z)dz=\\
=\int\limits_{0}^{1}\int\limits_{z}^{1}\int\limits_{-\sqrt{y}}^{\sqrt{y}}f(x,y,z)dxdydz = \int\limits_{0}^{1}dz\int\limits_{z}^{1}dy\int\limits_{-\sqrt{y}}^{\sqrt{y}}f(x,y,z)dx=\\
=\int\limits_{0}^{1}\int\limits_{0}^{y}\int\limits_{-\sqrt{y}}^{\sqrt{y}}f(x,y,z)dxdzdy = \int\limits_{0}^{1}dy\int\limits_{0}^{y}dz\int\limits_{-\sqrt{y}}^{\sqrt{y}}f(x,y,z)dx$$

Above integrals and set $B$ is obtained when considering $y,z$ as independent variables. If we consider $x,z$ as independent variables, then, of course, we will have
$$B=\left\lbrace \begin{array}{l}
-1 \leqslant x \leqslant 1 \\
0 \leqslant z \leqslant x^2 \\
 x^2 \leqslant y \leqslant 1
\end{array}
\right\rbrace \bigcup \left\lbrace \begin{array}{l}
-1 \leqslant x \leqslant 1 \\
x^2 \leqslant z \leqslant 1 \\
 z \leqslant y \leqslant 1
\end{array}
\right\rbrace = \\
=C=\left\lbrace \begin{array}{l}
0 \leqslant z \leqslant 1 \\
-1 \leqslant x \leqslant -\sqrt{z} \\
 x^2 \leqslant y \leqslant 1
\end{array}
\right\rbrace \bigcup \left\lbrace \begin{array}{l}
0 \leqslant z \leqslant 1 \\
\sqrt{z} \leqslant x \leqslant 1 \\
 x^2 \leqslant y \leqslant 1
\end{array}
\right\rbrace \bigcup \left\lbrace \begin{array}{l}
0 \leqslant z \leqslant 1 \\
-\sqrt{z} \leqslant x \leqslant \sqrt{z} \\
 z \leqslant y \leqslant 1
\end{array}
\right\rbrace$$

Integral for $C$:

$$\int\limits_{0}^{1}\int\limits_{-1}^{-\sqrt{z}}\int\limits_{x^2}^{1}f(x,y,z)dydxdz + \int\limits_{0}^{1}\int\limits_{\sqrt{z}}^{1}\int\limits_{x^2}^{1}f(x,y,z)dydxdz +\int\limits_{0}^{1}\int\limits_{-\sqrt{z}}^{\sqrt{z}}\int\limits_{z}^{1}f(x,y,z)dydxdz $$

All written integrals are $\frac{4}{5}$, when $f=1$.

Comment: zkutch, No. Please note that the changed order is $dydzdx$.

Comment: Thanks @Koro. I'll add it in a moment..

Comment: Still doesn't look right. $x$ should have constant values for upper/lower limits.

Comment: @Koro. We consider $x = x(y,z)$ right? Then it is not constant.

Comment: I'm thinking that since the integral will have some constant value. With your region B, since outermost limits are in (that is for x)  terms of $y$ so there will not be a constant value for the integral. Right?

Comment: Integral of course is constant, but in previous comment you wrote "$x$ should have constant values", in last "there will not be a constant value" - what you mean?

Comment: I meant upper/ lower limits for $x$ should be constant. With your B, you'll have something like $\int_{-\sqrt y}^{\sqrt y}\int_0^y \int_0^1 \text{(something)} \, dy dz dx=I$,say. I doubt that this $I$ may not have a constant value as outermost limits ($\pm \sqrt y$) are variable.

Comment: Are you confused by the function in the constraint? Let's look at $\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{x}f(x,y)dxdy$ for example. Are not it constant?

Comment: May be I bring clearness if I said, that integration by x is first, not last. Outermost, so are bounds for $y$. So we have $\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{y}\int_{-\sqrt{y}}^{\sqrt{y}}$ - Is these helpful?

Comment: zkutch, I'll get back to this. I seek clarification only for the limits. Your B looks ok but I don't think it is enough to evaluate the integral due to reason I mentioned in my earlier comment.

Comment: @Koro. I think I understand reason of our mutual misunderstanding: some books uses reverse order for integration variables. For exactness I wrote addition, where I wrote integration variables both: together and separately to avoid ambiguities.

Comment: zkutch, that is not the problem here. I'll clarify my point even more: Let's take $f(x,y,z)=x+y+z$. If we consider original limits integral evaluates to 5/7 but with your B, the integral evaluates to $y\sqrt y+y^2\sqrt y$.

Comment: @Koro. Here is not problem at all: take $f=1$. Then integral in OP and all my integrals are correctly evaluated to $\frac{4}{5}$, so $B$ is **correct**. I starting with taking independent variables on plane $Oxz$, as it can be found in history, but then your very first comment pushed me to plane $Oyz$. Of course I don't consider this as your fault - I myself should have stayed on my original intent, despite the comment mentioned. We are using reverse order for variable - that was misunderstanding. But all the integrals I obtained are correct and it will be only fair if someone appreciated it.

Comment: +1 Yes!! Now it looks correct. Although isn't $C$ redundant? That may be removed. Now your upper/lower limits of $x$ are constant (earlier they were variables as noted in our earlier discussion) and all limits are correct. Order dxdydz or dzdydx is never a confusion as long as the regions for integration are clear. And earlier your B was probably not correct as seen via example of $f$ I gave earlier. Had it been correct, integrals would have evaluated to the same value.

Comment: Sorry, but I nothing is changed in $B$ after our discussion, only in integrals in first 3 lines after definition ob  $B$  I wrote order of variables which are more familiar to you. Again sorry for repeating, nothing is changed. Now it is same as when was first time written - all history is kept in my answer and you are able to see what is changed and check my words, just click on link "edited".  As to $C$ it is one variant of how can be written integral with independent variables $x,z$ and, hope, will be helpful for somebody, who will read this question.

Comment: It's alright then. I may have misread $\cup$ in your B as $=$. 